# Does Python has @FindBys as Java?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, selenium

Any similar function available in Python-selenium for `@FindBys` as below ?
Java-Selenium:

```
@FindBys({@findby(), @findby()})
```

@FindBys - it means when the required WebElement objects need to match all of given criteria in @findby...

Comment: Pythoneers are unlikely to now what `@FindBys` means in Java. You need to explain it to get answers.